# How to remove highlight from menu item hover in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menuitem, antd

How could I remove `onHover` highlight from the [antd menu item](https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-fixed)?

I did the following:

```
<Header className="header">
    <Menu mode="horizontal" style={{ lineHeight: "50px" }}>
        <Menu.Item key="1">
        <Title {...props} />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">
        <FrequentItems {...props} />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2" style={{ float: "right" }}>
        <ProfileSettings {...props} />
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
    {/* <Content>
        <Title {...props} />
    </Content> */}
</Header>
```

The menu item appear as expected but it gives a underlined highlight when hovered over any menu item. How could I avoid this?

Currently on hover it looks like the following:

[image]

On hover blue line appears. I want one of the menu item to be a static text. Not clickable and color should not change on hover.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that works on antd v4:

```
.ant-menu-horizontal, .ant-menu-item::after, .ant-menu-submenu::after {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just an item to be not-clickable, static text, with no on-hover style- just use the [`disabled` prop of Menu.Item](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu.Item):

```
<Menu.Item disabled>
    Disbaled
</Menu.Item>
```

If you want to override the on-hover styling of all items you need to declare styles and apply them to Menu.Item:

You css class:

```
// ugly css hack
.modified-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent !important;
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

And add that as `className` prop:

```
<Menu.Item className="modified-item">
    Modified
</Menu.Item>
```

Here is a demo:

[image: Edit 6zlnxp931n]

Bear in mind, Ant design [urges not to do this](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#How-to-modify-Menu/Button(etc...)'s-style?):

> You can override its style, but we don't recommend doing so. antd is not only a set of React components but also a design specification.

Comment: .modified-item.ant-menu-submenu-active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent !important;
  color: inherit !important;
}

I would modify the css rule as so to avoid the underline indicator from reappearing on a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Hover creates pseudo element `::after` responsible for the line, so just hide it.

```
.ant-menu-root {
    > li:nth-of-type(1) {
        &::after {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```